# Count number of duplicate rows in SPARKSQL

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have requirement where i need to count number of duplicate rows in SparkSQL for Hive tables.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row
app_name="test"
conf = SparkConf().setAppName(app_name)
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.sql("select * from  DV_BDFRAWZPH_NOGBD_R000_SG.employee")
```

As of now i have hardcoded the table name, but it actually comes as parameter. That being said we don't know the number of columns or their names as well.In python pandas we have something like df.duplicated.sum() to count number of duplicate records. Do we have something like this here?

```
+---+---+---+
| 1 | A | B |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | A | B |
+---+---+---+
| 2 | B | E |
+---+---+---+
| 2 | B | E |
+---+---+---+
| 3 | D | G |
+---+---+---+
| 4 | D | G |
+---+---+---+
```

Here number of duplicate rows are 4. (for example)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You essentially want to `groupBy()` all the columns and `count()`, then select the sum of the counts for the rows where the count is greater than 1.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.groupBy(df.columns)\
    .count()\
    .where(f.col('count') > 1)\
    .select(f.sum('count'))\
    .show()
```

**Explanation**

After the grouping and aggregation, your data will look like this:

```python
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | A | B | 2 |
+---+---+---+---+
| 2 | B | E | 2 |
+---+---+---+---+
| 3 | D | G | 1 |
+---+---+---+---+
| 4 | D | G | 1 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Then use `where()` to filter only the rows with a count greater than 1, and select the sum. In this case, you will get the first 2 rows, which sum to 4.

Comment: Thanks, Now i would like to store this result in a variable and process in my regular python logic. How can i achieve this? when i am assigning this to a variable it is printing as None. But if i just run the above code, I am getting the result.

Comment: Thanks, you made my day. The solution is absolutely perfect and I am able to store into variable by using collect instead of show()

Comment: @pault when I need to check for only one column, is this the best way to do this? or, should I take total count and distinct count separately and figure out the duplicates?
Does groupBy is faster or slower than the above method??

Answer (score 0):

```
duplicate_rows_count = df.count() - df.distinct().count()
```