# check for duplicates in Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a simple and efficient way to check a python dataframe just for duplicates (not drop them) based on column(s)?

I want to check if a dataframe has dups based on a combination of columns and if it does, fail the process.

TIA.

Comment: You may also find the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48554666/5858851) to the question [Count number of duplicate rows in SPARKSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48554619/5858851) helpful.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The easiest way would be to check if the number of rows in the dataframe equals the number of rows after dropping duplicates.

```
if df.count() > df.dropDuplicates([listOfColumns]).count():
    raise ValueError('Data has duplicates')
```

Comment: Thanks - I thought of that and was wondering if this is the easiest way or I am missing a cool trick.

Comment: No, I can't imagine there would be some sort of `hasDuplicates` functionality. You could create a temp table and do something like `spark.sql('select count(*) - count(distinct col) from temp_view')`. It's certainly not an easier way, but it may (or may not) have better performance

Comment: by this method we can check only count, what about data ? 
Let me elaborate: in df1 column c1[1,2,3,4,5] another df2 column c2[1,1,2,3,4,5].

how will you verify that data duplicate

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but it sounds like the `join` or `subtract` methods might help.

Comment: What is the fastest way to do between the two top answers?

Answer (score 33):

If you also want to actually inspect the duplicates, you can do

```
df \
    .groupby(['column1', 'column2']) \
    .count() \
    .where('count > 1') \
    .sort('count', ascending=False) \
    .show()
```

Comment: This unfortunately only shows the duplicates *beyond the first one*.  If, for instance, I want to flag all data with duplicate values on a column (or list of columns), then this will miss the first instance.  :(

Answer (score 9):

Another way to inspect the duplicates would be :

```
df.exceptAll(df.dropDuplicates([listOfColumns]))
```

Answer (score 3):

To get a pyspark dataframe with duplicate rows, can use below code:

```
df_duplicates = df.groupBy(df.columns).count().filter("count > 1")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can count the number of distinct rows on a set of columns and compare it with the number of total rows. If they are the same, there is no duplicate rows. If the number of distinct rows is less than the total number of rows, duplicates exist.

`df.select(list_of_columns).distinct().count()`
and
`df.select(list_of_columns).count()`

Answer (score 0):

Calling `count()` twice is not necessary, the two counts can be obtained with a single action.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']

counts_df = df.select([
    F.countDistinct(*cols).alias('n_unique'),
    F.count('*').alias('n_rows')
])
n_unique, n_rows = counts_df.collect()[0]
```

Now with the `n_unique`, `n_rows` the dupes/unique percentage can be logged, the process can be failed etc.