# Pyspark Similar Operation for `df[df.duplicated()]` in Pandas

Tags: pandas, pyspark

Is there any similar operation for checking the duplicated values in a dataframe in spark?

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't any that does the same, but there are ways to do it in pyspark.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59564304/2956135

Answer (score 2):

You could use the answer in stackoverflow.com/a/59564304/2956135 that Emma linked:

```
if df.count() > df.dropDuplicates([listOfColumns]).count():
raise ValueError('Data has duplicates')
```

Or, make a df with the duplicates from the two columns and inspect them there:

```
df.exceptAll(df.drop_duplicates(['ID', 'ID2', 'Number'])).show()
```