# PySpark - Get indices of duplicate rows

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say I have a PySpark data frame, like so:

```
+--+--+--+--+
|a |b |c |d |
+--+--+--+--+
|1 |0 |1 |2 |
|0 |2 |0 |1 |
|1 |0 |1 |2 |
|0 |4 |3 |1 |
+--+--+--+--+
```

How can I create a column marking all of the duplicate rows, like so:

```
+--+--+--+--+--+
|a |b |c |d |e |
+--+--+--+--+--+
|1 |0 |1 |2 |1 |
|0 |2 |0 |1 |0 |
|1 |0 |1 |2 |1 |
|0 |4 |3 |1 |0 |
+--+--+--+--+--+
```

I attempted it using the groupBy and aggregate functions to no avail.

Comment: Not an exact dupe, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48554666/5858851) is one approach. Try: `df.groupBy(df.columns).count().show()`

Answer (score 14):

Just to expand on [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50865803/pyspark-get-indices-of-duplicate-rows#comment88734195_50865803):

You can group by all of the columns and use [`pyspark.sql.functions.count()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.count) to determine if a column is duplicated:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.groupBy(df.columns).agg((f.count("*")>1).cast("int").alias("e")).show()
#+---+---+---+---+---+
#|  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|
#+---+---+---+---+---+
#|  1|  0|  1|  2|  1|
#|  0|  2|  0|  1|  0|
#|  0|  4|  3|  1|  0|
#+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Here we use `count("*") > 1` as the aggregate function, and cast the result to an `int`. The `groupBy()` will have the consequence of dropping the duplicate rows. Depending on your needs, this may be sufficient.

However, if you'd like to keep all of the rows, you can use a `Window` function like shown in the other answers OR you can use a `join()`:

```python
df.join(
    df.groupBy(df.columns).agg((f.count("*")>1).cast("int").alias("e")),
    on=df.columns,
    how="inner"
).show()
#+---+---+---+---+---+
#|  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|
#+---+---+---+---+---+
#|  1|  0|  1|  2|  1|
#|  1|  0|  1|  2|  1|
#|  0|  2|  0|  1|  0|
#|  0|  4|  3|  1|  0|
#+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Here we inner join the original dataframe with the one that is the result of the `groupBy()` above on all of the columns.

Answer (score 8):

Define a `window` function to check whether the `count` of rows when grouped by all columns is greater than 1. If yes, its a duplicate (1) else not duplicate (0)

```
allColumns = df.columns
import sys
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import window as w
windowSpec = w.Window.partitionBy(allColumns).rowsBetween(-sys.maxint, sys.maxint)

df.withColumn('e', f.when(f.count(f.col('d')).over(windowSpec) > 1, f.lit(1)).otherwise(f.lit(0))).show(truncate=False)
```

which should give you

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
|a  |b  |c  |d  |e  |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|1  |0  |1  |2  |1  |
|1  |0  |1  |2  |1  |
|0  |2  |0  |1  |0  |
|0  |4  |3  |1  |0  |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

**Updated**

As @pault [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50865803/pyspark-get-indices-of-duplicate-rows/50878031#comment88758851_50873969), you can eliminate `when`, `col` and `lit` by casting the `boolean` to `integer`:

```
df.withColumn('e', (f.count('*').over(windowSpec) > 1).cast('int')).show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: No need for the `when`, `col`, or `lit` here- you can cast the condition to integer: `df.withColumn('e', (f.count('*').over(windowSpec) > 1).cast('int')).show(truncate=False)`

Comment: Thanks @pault for the comment :) really helpful , I included your comment in my answer

Answer (score 2):

I think the pandas_udf can handle this in an easier way. Firstly, you need to create a pandas UDF which takes a Series and returns True for the duplicated rows. Then, simply use withColumn to mark the duplicated rows. Here is my suggested code:

```
@pandas_udf('boolean')
def duplicate_finder(s: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return s.duplicated(keep=False)

df.withColumn('Duplicated', duplicate_finder('DESIRED_COLUMN')).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Partition your dataframe with all the columns and than apply dense_rank.

```
import sys
from pyspark.sql.functions import dense_rank
from pyspark.sql import window as w

df.withColumn('e', dense_rank().over(w.Window.partitionBy(df.columns))).show()
```

Comment: `AnalysisException: u'Window function dense_rank() requires window to be ordered`

Answer (score 0):

df1=df_interr.groupBy("Item_group","Item_name","price").count().filter("count > 1")