# getting duplicate count but retaining duplicate rows in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to find the duplicate count of rows in a pyspark dataframe. I found a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50865803/pyspark-get-indices-of-duplicate-rows) 
but it only outputs a binary flag. I would like to have the actual count for each row.
To use the orignal post's example, if I have a dataframe like so:

```
+--+--+--+--+
|a |b |c |d |
+--+--+--+--+
|1 |0 |1 |2 |
|0 |2 |0 |1 |
|1 |0 |1 |2 |
|0 |4 |3 |1 |
|1 |0 |1 |2 |
+--+--+--+--+
```

I would like to result in something like:

```
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|a |b |c |d |row_count  |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|1 |0 |1 |2 |3          |
|0 |2 |0 |1 |0          |
|1 |0 |1 |2 |3          |
|0 |4 |3 |1 |0          |
|1 |0 |1 |2 |3          |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

Is this possible?
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `df` is your input dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import *


w = (Window.partitionBy([F.col("a"), F.col("b"), F.col("c"), F.col("D")]))
df=df.select(F.col("a"), F.col("b"), F.col("c"), F.col("D"), F.count(F.col("a")).over(w).alias("row_count"))
```

If, as per your example, you want to replace every count `1` with `0` do:

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import *


w = (Window.partitionBy([F.col("a"), F.col("b"), F.col("c"), F.col("D")]))
df=df.select(F.col("a"), F.col("b"), F.col("c"), F.col("D"), F.count(F.col("a")).over(w).alias("row_count")).select("a", "b", "c", "d", F.when(F.col("row_count")==F.lit(1), F.lit(0)). otherwise(F.col("row_count")).alias("row_count"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight. However, if I have lots of columns, is there a way to do it without specifying each column to window by?

Comment: Yes, if you want to include ALL columns - you can use list comprehension and do: ```[F.col(str(col_)) for col_ in df.columns]``` if you just want a subset you can add proper ```if``` inside