# Labelling duplicates in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am trying to label the duplicates in my PySpark DataFrame based on their group, while having the full length data frame. Below is an example code.

```py
data= [
    ("A", "2018-01-03"),
    ("A", "2018-01-03"),
    ("A", "2018-01-03"),
    ("B", "2019-01-03"),
    ("B", "2019-01-03"),
    ("B", "2019-01-03"),
    ("C", "2020-01-03"),
    ("C", "2020-01-03"),
    ("C", "2020-01-03"),
]

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

spark= SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df= spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=["Group", "Date"])
df= df.withColumn("Date", F.to_date("Date", "yyyy-MM-dd"))


from pyspark.sql import Window
windowSpec= Window.partitionBy("Group").orderBy(F.asc("Date"))

df.withColumn("group_number", F.dense_rank().over(windowSpec)).orderBy("Date").show()
```

This is my current output and although it is correct since the code ranks "Date" based on its group but that was not my desired outcome.

```
+-----+----------+------------+
|Group|      Date|group_number|
+-----+----------+------------+
|    A|2018-01-03|           1|
|    A|2018-01-03|           1|
|    A|2018-01-03|           1|
|    B|2019-01-03|           1|
|    B|2019-01-03|           1|
|    B|2019-01-03|           1|
|    C|2020-01-03|           1|
|    C|2020-01-03|           1|
|    C|2020-01-03|           1|
+-----+----------+------------+
```

I was hoping my output to look like this

```
+-----+----------+------------+
|Group|      Date|group_number|
+-----+----------+------------+
|    A|2018-01-03|           1|
|    A|2018-01-03|           1|
|    A|2018-01-03|           1|
|    B|2019-01-03|           2|
|    B|2019-01-03|           2|
|    B|2019-01-03|           2|
|    C|2020-01-03|           3|
|    C|2020-01-03|           3|
|    C|2020-01-03|           3|
+-----+----------+------------+
```

Any suggestions? I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50865803/pyspark-get-indices-of-duplicate-rows) but this is just a binary solution! I have more than 2 groups in my dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the partitionBy function when you declare your windowSpec. By specifying the column "Group" in partionBy, you're telling the program to do a dense_rank() for each partition based on the "Date". So the output is correct. If we look at group A, they have the same dates, thus they all have a group_rank of 1. Moving on to group B, they all have the same dates, thus they have a group rank of 1.

So a quick fix for your problem is to remove the partionBy in your windowSpec.

EDIT: If you were to group by the Group column, the following is another solution: you can use a user defined function (UDF) as the second argument parameter in the df.withColumn(). In this UDF, you would specify your input/output like a normal function. Something like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def new_column(group):
  return ord(group) - 64 # Unicode integer equivalent as A is 65

funct = udf(new_column, IntegerType())

df.withColumn("group_number", funct(df["Group"])).orderBy("Date").show()
```

If you were to use UDF for for the Date, you would need some way to keep track of Dates. An example:

```
import datetime

date_dict = {}
def new_column(date_obj):
   if len(date_dict) > 0 and date_dict[date_obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")]:
     return date_dict[date_obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")]
   date_dict[date_obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")] = len(date_obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) + 1
   return date_dict[date_obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")]
```

Comment: Hi there! thank you for the solution! Could you please amend the return statement in your function to reflect `new_column` taking a date as input? currently the return stamens doesn't look right.

Comment: I would actually just use your solution and just remove the partionBy portion. Thinking about it more, I initially thought you were ranking based on the group (in which case we could use Unicode conversion to easily get the ranks). But then I realized you were ranking based on the Date. I'll edit the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Yes, you are correct! removing the `partionBy` statement works! I would be grateful if you could make the amendment to your code regarding your function taking a `date` i.e. `datetime` as input and I will mark it as the solution! Thank you so much!

Comment: I get this error from your function `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime`

Comment: Didn't realize you already casted it into a datetime object. I assumed it was a string.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to rank over all the groups not in each group so you don't need to partition by the `Window`, just order by `Group` and `Date` will give you the desired output:

```
windowSpec = Window.orderBy(F.asc("Group"), F.asc("Date"))

df.withColumn("group_number", F.dense_rank().over(windowSpec)).orderBy("Date").show()

#+-----+----------+------------+
#|Group|      Date|group_number|
#+-----+----------+------------+
#|    A|2018-01-03|           1|
#|    A|2018-01-03|           1|
#|    A|2018-01-03|           1|
#|    B|2019-01-03|           2|
#|    B|2019-01-03|           2|
#|    B|2019-01-03|           2|
#|    C|2020-01-03|           3|
#|    C|2020-01-03|           3|
#|    C|2020-01-03|           3|
#+-----+----------+------------+
```

And you surely **don't need any UDF** as the other answer suggests.